# d3 svg overlay on top of leaflet map not working with ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, leaflet

I am trying to set an svg from d3 in a leaflet map with ReactJs but it does nothing.

The leaflet map appears alright but the svg layer doesn't.

I tried a few methods but none worked. I tried  L.svgOverlay().addTo(map); and L.svg().addTo(map) without success

below is the ReactComponent and the circles.json I'm trying to plot

What am I missing here?

```
export const MainPage = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        var container = L.DomUtil.get("map");

        if (container != null) {
            container._leaflet_id = null;
        }
        const map = L.map('map').setView([-41.2858, 174.7868], 13);
        L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
            maxZoom: 18
        }).addTo(map);

        L.svgOverlay().addTo(map);

        var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).select("svg"),
            g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

        d3.json("circles.json", function (collection) {
            collection.objects.forEach(function (d) {
                d.LatLng = new L.LatLng(d.circle.coordinates[0],
                    d.circle.coordinates[1])
            })

            var feature = g.selectAll("circle")
                .data(collection.objects)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .style("fill", "steelblue")
                .style("opacity", .6)
                .style("fill", "red")
                .attr("r", 20);

            function update() {
                feature.attr("transform",
                    function (d) {
                        return "translate(" +
                            map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).x + "," +
                            map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).y + ")";
                    }
                )
            }
            map.on("viewreset", update);
            update();
        });
    }, [])

    return <div id="map" style={{ height: "100vh" }}></div>;
}
```

```
{
    "objects": [
        {
            "circle": {
                "coordinates": [
                    -41.28,
                    174.77
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "circle": {
                "coordinates": [
                    -41.29,
                    174.76
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "circle": {
                "coordinates": [
                    -41.30,
                    174.79
                ]
            }
        },
    ]
}
```